# android connect to local host from connectify me to consure a web service

Tags: android, rest, connection, jersey

First of all I will tell you what can I do:

- I can connect my real device to my servlets on my website using my computer IP
- I can connect my emulator to my servlets on my website using 10.0.2.2 IP
- I can connect my emulator to my web services using 10.0.2.2 IP

**My problem.**

I can't connect my real device to the web services;

I tried this (It works for emulator);

```
public class Client {

    private String server;

    public Client(String server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    private String getBase() {
        return server;
    }

    public String getBaseURI(String str) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 3000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            int timeoutSocket = 5000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(getBase() + str);
            getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
            result = getResult(response).toString();
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
        return result;
    }

    public String getBaseURIText(String str) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 3000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            int timeoutSocket = 5000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(getBase() + str);
            getRequest.addHeader("accept", "text/plain");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
            result = getResult(response).toString();
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

 private StringBuilder getResult(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())), 1024);
            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) 
                result.append(output);

            return result;      
      }
}
```

Then I call that client like this:

```
Client client = new Client("http://46.57.164.64:8080/test2/eattel/");
            client.getBaseURI("image/image");
```

**This totally works for emulators. but now for my real device :(**

I connect my real device to my computer using cable .

my computer and my device are connected to `connectify-me` wireless network.

please help

**I am sure it is something about IP**

Answer (score 2):

I think what went wrong here is you are connecting your computer and your real device through a cable. Your real device should be connected to wireless network throngh WiFi. Your computer also should be connected the Wireless Network either via a cable or WiFi. Then, once you type your computer IP address on the Internet Browser of Real Device, you should be able to see the home page of the server that you are running on your computer. If that is coming your application can communicate with your web services in the computer. If that is not coming that means your IP Addresses are not set properly Wireless Network. You might have to restart the Wireless Network and try out again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to discover your computer ip address for connectify connection? 
If you are using windows OS, Go to command prompt, type ipconfig and search the ipv4 address under Wireless LAN Adapter Local Area Connection. It usually start with 192.168.xxx.xxx if you use connectify